# How to find the maximum number formed with the digits of a given number WITHOUT ARRAYS

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm really wondering how to solve this problem without using arrays. I have been literally scratching my head for hours without success. Help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Please show your code solving it using arrays and perhaps someone can point you in the right direction.

Comment: At least you should give some specifications such as the length of the number, and also an example of input/output if you do not provide a code attempt

Comment: The length of the input can be whatever integer, positive or negative. I did not provide a code attempt because the only way I know how to tackle this is using arrays, which I am not allowed to, so showing you how I solved it using that way has nothing to do with the question. For the number 3825 the output should be 8532 and for -918 it should be -189

Answer (score 1):

Let me show you how to achieve this with the number 12365:

```
12365 (largest digit : 6)
62315 (largest remaining digit : 5)
65312 (largest remaining digit : 3)
65312 (largets remaining digit : 2)
65321
```

The calculations can be performed, using simple `MOD()` calculations.

Comment: So basically sorting in descending order, just with digits.

Comment: So basically you do an selection sort.